# Loading jQuery multiple times in the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm implementing a plug-in that's embeddable in different sites (a la Meebo, Wibiya), and I want to use jQuery. Problem is, the site I'm embedding to, may already have a jQuery script loaded.

The question is, what's the best approach for this kind of problem:

1. Should I just check if jQuery is already loaded and if so, use the original site's jQuery, otherwise load it myself? If I use this approach, am I not risking comaptibility problems (i.e. the site uses an old version of jQuery)?
2. Should I load jQuery myself (whether it's already loaded or not) and call "jQuery.noConflict(true)" when it's finished loading? If so, how can I make sure that *my* jQuery has finished loading (hooking to the onLoad event doesn't seem to work all the time, and polling for "jQuery" won't work for obvious reasons)?
3. Should I do something else?

Thanks.

Comment: in case of a plugin that need to run anywhere i would suggest you use pure JS and no frameworks... Butcheck for jQuery, incl. the version and include it, if its not here. (Or the wrong version)

Comment: Agree with Meo - you should streamline the JS as much as possible, and that would mean not using a third party plugin (jQuery). Keep the files as small as possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can check if jQuery is already loaded using the code:

```
if(jQuery) {
     //it's loaded
} else {
     //it's not loaded
}
```

You can also check the version of the loaded jQuery using:

```
$().jquery;
```

this will return a string like "1.4.1"

Using these two methods you can see what the site has already loaded and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

[By this blog article](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/03/check-if-jqueryjs-is-loaded.html)

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {  
    // jQuery is not loaded  
} else {
    // jQuery is loaded
}
```